# Quarto render single html file in a project without rendering the whole project

Tags: r, quarto

I have a vanilla quarto blog that has multiple posts. I have structured it so that extra files needed for a blog post are saved alongside the post.
One of my blogs has another quarto file as an extra file that I want to render without rendering the whole blog.

Eg the main blog article is `posts/2022-10-28-myblog/index.qmd` and I have the extra file `posts/2022-10-28-myblog/extra.qmd`.

When I run `setwd("posts/2022-10-28-myblog/")` and `quarto::quarto_render(input = "extra.qmd", output_file = "extra.html")` it first renders the extra file (good), but then it renders the blog article and tries all other blog files as well (not wanted) and it also removes the output of the extra file (totally not good). Instead I want to only render the extra file.

I have already tried the following:

- `output_format = "html"` in the `quarto_render` function,
- `as_job = FALSE` in the `quarto_render` function,
- moved the extra files to another folder (eg `posts/2022-10-28-myblog/examples/extra.Rmd`)
- created a separate Rproject in the folder (and activated it),

but it always wants to render the whole blog if its in a subfolder of the blog...

(I am using Quarto 1.0.36)

Comment: I will add this link here as I think it is relevant: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/3674

Answer (score 1):

My current workaround is to have a `render_only_this.R` script which copies the files to a tempdir, renders it, and copies the resulting file back to the main folder.

It looks something like the following

```
owd <- setwd("posts/2022-10-28-myblog")

tmpdir <- tempdir()
ff <- list.files()
file.copy(ff, tmpdir, overwrite = TRUE)

owd2 <- setwd(tmpdir)
quarto::quarto_render(input = "extra.qmd", output_file = "extra.html")

# either copy the file back to owd2; or deploy somewhere or so
file.copy("extra.html", owd2)

# clean up
unlink(ff)
unlink(c("extra.html", "figure", "rsconnect"), recursive = TRUE)
setwd(owd)
```

Comment: When I create a `book` or blog (website) project in `quarto` I can easily say `quarto render chaptername.qmd` from the command line and only the chapter will be rendered to html.  `quarto` will also re-run any indexing needed for the whole site.

Comment: That renders the other files for me as well and puts the output in the `../../_site/posts/YOURBLOGPOST` folder...