# Quarto ignore non index.qmd files in Blog when rendering

Tags: r, quarto

This question is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74237333/3048453).

I have a Quarto blog where I save additional quarto files next to the respective blog articles (`index.qmd`), which are then displayed within the blog as example code.

When I render the blog, the additional files are picked up and rendered as separate blog articles as well.

For example, my files look like this, where `extra.qmd` is included in the `index.qmd` file as part of the blog

```markdown
posts/
  2022-10-31-ex1/
    index.qmd      # should be rendered as the blog article (works)
    extra.qmd      # should be ignored by quarto and not be its own article (does not work)
```

How can I tell Quarto to only render `index.qmd` files as blog articles and ignore all other  quarto files?

One possible solution is to mark all of the extra files as drafts (YAML header `draft: true`), but that changes the content of the extra file, which I don't want.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found is to use customize the `./index.qmd` file defining the listings like so:

```yaml
listing:
  contents:
    - "posts/*/index.qmd"
```